# How to default in a key value and retrieve existing record on first load?

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a new screen with one new table (AMClockItem) where the key field is the employee ID. I want it to default to the logged in user employee ID. If there isn't an AMClockItem record for the employee it will treat it as a new record, but if there is an existing record for the employee I want it to retrieve the existing record. This all works perfectly EXCEPT the very first time the screen is loaded. The logged in user defaults properly but it doesn't retrieve the existing record. If I click Cancel or change another field it will retrieve the record properly.

My Graph

```
public PXSelect<AMClockItem, Where<AMClockItem.employeeID, Equal<Optional<AMClockItem.employeeID>>>> header;
```

DAC:

```
public abstract class employeeID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<employeeID> { }

    protected Int32? _EmployeeID;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [ProductionEmployeeSelector]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
         Where<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Null)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Employee ID")]
    public virtual Int32? EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._EmployeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._EmployeeID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

On first load, it defaults in the correct logged in user, but the rest of the fields are blank, treating it as a new record.

[image]

I hit the cancel button and the existing record loads correctly.

[image]

I tried looking for a similar Acumatica screen but can't find an example where a key value is defaulted in on load. Is there a way to force the existing record to load the first time you visit the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is allowed, there's no mechanism that selects record like that to my knowledge as well.

I suspect the formulas do not execute in order too. 
Make sure all key fields have proper value. Record can't be selected if one of the key fields resolve to null on load.

If some key fields initialization are dependent on other key fields initialization decorate them with the `PXDependsOnFields` attribute:

```
[PXDependsOnFields(typeof(employeeID))]
```

Comment: In this situation, employeeid is the only key field.

Comment: Maybe adding the dependency attribute on 'AccessInfo.userID' could help.

Comment: The issue could also be that the Defaulting mechanism is invoked after record selection, in that case I wouldn't know how to resolve the issue unfortunately. To be sure key works properly, you can copy paste the URL in a new tab with the key initialized in URL. This method is known to work properly to default the blank document keys: Example for employee screen which has AcctCD key: /Main?ScreenId=EP203000&AcctCD=EP00000001

Comment: It works correctly if the employee ID is in the URL like /Main?CompanyID=JAMS+-+DEV&ScreenId=AM315000&EmployeeID=EP00000002 but on the very first load the URL is /Main?CompanyID=JAMS+-+DEV&ScreenId=AM315000 and it doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is likely that PXDefault is not a proper mechanism to select the DAC key. Otherwise it should have put the key parameter in the URL. Unfortunately I don't know another mechanism to initialize keys for record selection, it might require some hacks to make this work like calling refresh action from JavaScript when page has effectively finished loading.

Comment: To confirm further that record selection occurs after record defaulting: after it successfully defaulted the field value, invoke Cancel action (your current workaround) and see if the key is added in the URL.

Comment: Where would I invoke the Cancel action? It doesn't look like I can put it in an event handler.

Comment: By clicking on the cancel button, otherwise with JavaScript when the document has loaded (this won't pass certification).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PageLoadBehavior property of "DataSource". Select "SearchSavedKeys". This will help.